# how to handle "unknown error" in perl module compilation

Tags: perl

when I try to use a "third part module" in my perl script, I got some error message like
**"unknown error, compilation failed in require at ... line xxx"**
nothing else and the line mentioned in the error message is exact the same line I "use the module"...

my question is: are there any good practice to handle this situation? like a list to check or something else. thanks in advance.

Comment: For errors such as these it can be helpful to specify your system architecture and Perl version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrade to a newer version of Perl.  [This bug](http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=49472) was fixed nearly two years ago.

Comment: Thankfully it appears that this issue is only in 5.10.0 and not 5.10.1, so no one running any "reasonable" version these days should see it.

Answer (score 5):

Two Tools that can be helpful here are

- [Carp::Always](http://p3rl.org/Carp::Always)
- [Devel::SimpleTrace](http://p3rl.org/Devel::SimpleTrace)

:

```
perl -MCarp::Always myscript.pl
```

This will hopefully emit a more comprehensive backtrace of what lead to the problem.

Also important to note that

```
use Foo;
```

expands as

```
BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import }
```

so its possibly an indication there is a syntax error in 'Foo' and it needs to be looked into.

Sometimes it is helpful to run a syntax-only check on 'Foo'

```
perl -c path/to/Foo.pm
```